# Asus max 5.5 adb won't recognize device after unlock bootloader

Tags: adb, twrp, asus-zenfone-3

Hey guys so I have encountered this problem multiple times. Followed this thread for unlocking bootloader and initiating root: http://www.symbianize.com/showthread.php?t=1411778

so far I went up to unlocking bootloader successfully without any hindrances but to my dismay after unlocking bootloader, adb won't recognize my device and can't proceed to flash TWRP. Tried rebooting to fastboot and typing in cmd `adb reboot bootloader` but did not proceed because as I said the device isn't recognized. Using windows 8 64-bit. Device is Asus zenfone 3 max variant 5.5 (zc553kl) updated to latest firmware nougat 7.1.1

I have usb and adb drivers installed, but the device doesn't even show up in the device manager, so `adb reboot bootloader` didn't find anything to reboot.

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Furthermore ADB is not used in flashing images (i.e. a custom recovery), you use fastboot instead: `fastboot flash recovery twrp-xxx.img` for example. Perhaps you are confusing commands?

Comment: Weird either USB debugging isn't turned on or your USB cable may be defective or drivers aren't installed correctly. ADB was recognizing your device BEFORE the bootloader unlock?

Comment: Could you if possible make some screenshots of commands line window and your device manager? I see you don't have enough reputation to add images, pleqse use an online host

Comment: Will do update you later on if I have the time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes device was detected before bootloader unlock. But after unlocking device wasn't recognized anymore

Comment: Bypass what? All you need is to enable USB Debugging in the developpers options again; Simply like that.

Comment: well just an update. Did unlocking again and restarted after fastboot but oddly enough my phone didn't go back to factory settings. I did unlock bootloader for about 2 times but the same thing happens. Dunno what the problem is now

Comment: Do you even understand things I'm telling you to do? I said now thr bootloader is unlocked,, go to `settings > about device > type 7 times on Build number> go back to settings, now you should see Developer options > enable USB debugging`

Comment: Besides, what is the commands you are using to unlock the bootloader

Comment: Well it seems you're the one who doesn't understand. Let me say it again. The instruction as to unlock bootloader I already provided the link in the main post, I assume you didn't even take a look at it to even see it is legitimate. BEFORE unlocking bootloader I ALREADY ENABLED usb debugging. Now, AFTER unlocking bootloader I restarted the device. After restarting the device turned on and the data wasn't erased. Pin code, finger print, apps and games all retained. I would probably assume the unlocking process was somewhat wrong or incomplete.

Comment: You never answered my question as to know if the USB debugging option is enabled. No I didn't bother checking the instructions you provided since I assume you knew what you were doing. If no data was deleted, I presume the bootloader is still locked. You can check that with Fastboot `fastboot get status`

Comment: besides, this thread is not in English.